# AJAX .send() vs .send("")

Tags: javascript, ajax, http

When sending an empty AJAX request, are there any technical differences between:

```
xhr.send();
```

and:

```
xhr.send("");
```

Mainly from a...

- Cross browser support/behaviour (especially this one)
- Actual data sent in HTTP headers (and is it the same in all browsers?)
- The way the JavaScript expression is parsed and interpreted (Memory, CPU usage, parsing time... I know this is very **MINIMAL** but I would like to know, out of curiosity and for educational reasons)

...point of view.

Comment: This might be useful: http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-send()-method

Comment: so .send() is equivalent to .send(null), still have no clear idea about .send("") though..

Comment: @ heytools: Keep reading. It quite clearly says what to do if the argument is a string. (I don't think it ends up making any practical difference, but I haven't thoroughly read that, either.)

Comment: Oh nice, so I get it .send(null) should make way less backend activity than sending an empty string. Would all browsers follow these specs? Isn't there a risk that some old browsers would treat the send method differently?